# How to navigate XAMPP/myPHP and verify if mySQL is functional?

Tags: xampp

Recently downloaded XAMPP on Windows and I would like to request a tutorial on how to navigate the program. I'm not sure how to open myPHP and test SQL Queries or create databases. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to XAMPP,

By now you should have the program installed in the location of your choice from the Apache friends website. I understand that it is quite difficult to get started on a new project utilizing unfamiliar tools, by the end of this short tutorial you can start building all sorts of ideas!

---

**1. To start, open the application from the desktop. On windows, the opening screen will display as shown below. Click on "Start" for the Apache and MySQL modules.**

***[Homepage of XAMPP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK4zr.png)***

The port value will be 80 for Apache in most cases, this varies dependent on module type and other applications with respect to their assigned port numbers.

These can be viewed by navigating to "Netstat" which displays socket properties. Configurations can be completed under "Config" in the top right of the application and under "Service and Port Settings". Common issues to modules not working correctly is due to port error or overlapping and changing values will prevent this.

---

**2. The status of the modules is portrayed in the panel below. In your preferred internet browser, type** ***"http://localhost"***. **The dashboard of Apache with given instructions will show when entered. Navigate to "PHPMyAdmin" at the top right of the webpage.**

***[PHPMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gICfn.png)***

The critical step for this dashboard to be functional is to have the MySQL module running. On the left of the screen, databases are displayed when created.

---

**3. Next, type "`Create database test;`" in the SQL tab queries text box. The console is displayed at the bottom of the page representing errors and program messages. Click the "Go" button. The "test" database will join the list of databases on the left side of the window.**

This verifies that MySQL and Apache servers are functional on the local computer. URL's define locations for pages that are requested and identify webserver addresses. Apache is an application that provides access to these requested locations to the user.

---

**4. A simple webpage can be generated by the user through XAMPP. Create a .txt file with its contents only including "`<h1>StackOverFlow</h1>`" and under this type "`<p>I am learning, this is a test</p>`". Save this file in the htdocs folder inside the xampp installation location as "StackOverFlow.html". Go to your browser and insert** ***"http://localhost/StackOverFlow.html"***.

The process listed allows the browser URL to request the existing web server to obtain the page's contents ***"http://localhost/StackOverFlow.html"***

---

**5. Next, go back to step 3 where queries will be used to construct tables for relationships of entities and test values.**

**The test database was created previously and still exists. Keep the query tab open and edit the initial script to be "`create database if not exists test;`". Add the statement "`drop database if exists test;`". These steps permit the program to refresh the database and scripted queries each time the user clicks "Go" resulting in the removal of overlapping data.**

Two tables will be created and their relationship can be expressed shortly. In the next step, a simple Company and Product association is used. Basic terms to know to write SQL queries:

- SELECT -> extracts data from a database
- UPDATE -> updates data in a database
- DELETE -> deletes data from a database
- INSERT INTO -> inserts new data into a database
- CREATE DATABASE -> creates a new database
- CREATE TABLE -> creates a new table
- DROP TABLE -> deletes a  table
- VarChar -> Varying variable character of desired length
- Char -> character of set length
- Not Null -> term cannot be null
- Date -> date term reference
- Integer -> term must be an integer
- Key -> uniquely identifies row(s) in a table

[SQL Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_syntax.asp)

---

**6. Insert "`use test;`" under the creation of the database query. Then structure the code in an organized fashion for easy reading for the user.
Add "`create table Company(`" and under insert "`companyName varchar(40) not null primary key,`", then "`street varchar(40),`". Also, "`city varchar(40),`" and "`province char(2),`" with "`postalCode char(6));`".**

**Add "`create table Product(`" and under insert "`producedBy varchar(40) not null,`", then "`dateMade date not null,`". Also, "`productName varchar(40) not null);`".**

The *Company* and *Product* tables are now created with specific dimensions, ordering, and terms.

---

**7. There are many types of relations within SQL that allow individuals to retrieve specific data, store, and construct relationships between many tables with set parameters through additional queries. This example is simple where *producedBy* references the *companyName* containing relevant data.**

**Position the following below both the table queries:**

**[Test values for Company table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNByf.png)**

**[Test values for Product table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tHLy.png)**

**Select "Go" and this will create tables that can be viewed by clicking the database "test" on the left side.**

Here, the statement `INSERT INTO` is used to input the data below into the table with the parameters created. Appropriate ordering of data from first to last must match with the corresponding table. Invalid inputs will result in the console returning an error. Selecting specific data from a larger database with numerous tables can be accessed by "`SELECT * FROM TABLENAME`", creating temporary relations and returning desired data. This concept can be further discussed in another tutorial. The interface is extremely useful and can be implemented within html websites to store, calculate, or retrieve data/user processes.

---

XAMPP is an exceptional tool to create and integrate into different areas of development, I would recommend taking a look at ***"https://www.w3schools.com/"*** to further learn SQL, HTML, and other skills to extend your range of capabilities.

Thank you for going through this tutorial! If you have any questions feel free to leave a comment.